# Can the user be displayed first than on the bottom in the Leaderboard search?

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash, winterbash-leaderboard

In the Winter Bash Leaderboard, if we search a user by their username, it gets displayed at the bottom, below the page selector.

For example,
[image]

It'd be nice if the user were displayed on the top of the other users.